What defense do those with a pre-tribulational view of the rapture have regarding Paul's use of "day of Christ" in 2 Thessalonians 2?
From my understanding, the pre-tribulational rapture doctrine suggests that separate terms are used for the rapture event and Christ's complete arrival at the end of the tribulation. Specifically, proponents assert that the Day of the Lord refers to Christ's final arrival, while a term like the Day of Christ pertains to the rapture event. I believe John MacArthur and others have supported this perspective, stating that the Day of Christ refers specifically to the rapture.
I am personally very persuaded of the opposite—that these various terms actually refer to the same event, each emphasizing different aspects of it. Regardless of the broader debate, focusing specifically on the Day of Christ: if this term indeed refers to the rapture event, how does one reconcile the belief that the rapture occurs prior to the onset of the great tribulation in light of 2 Thessalonians 2:1–3?
2 Thessalonians 2:1–3 says:

"Now we beseech you, brethren, by the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ, and by our gathering together unto him, That ye be not soon shaken in mind, or be troubled, neither by spirit, nor by word, nor by letter as from us, as that the day of Christ is at hand. Let no man deceive you by any means: for that day shall not come, except there come a falling away first, and that man of sin be revealed, the son of perdition..."

I find it difficult to see how one could justify the rapture occurring prior to the tribulation when considering passages like this. If the Day of Christ is distinct from the Day of the Lord, wouldn't this passage at least suggest a mid-tribulational view of the rapture, given that Paul explicitly states the day of Christ will not occur until a falling away happens and the man of sin is revealed?
I suspect that those with a pre-tribulational view might point to the word "revealed" (ἀποκαλυφθῇ) as the key to their understanding. Perhaps the argument is that the man of sin being "revealed" is not the same event as him taking power or standing in the Holy Place? Do they interpret this as merely his coming to existence on earth, rather than his active rebellion or defilement of the temple? By no means am I am an expert in Biblical Greek, but I find this to be an unlikely interpretation of the term/phrase.
Perhaps the argument instead interprets this passage as suggesting that the rapture occurs after the falling away but before the man of sin is revealed? In other words, they might propose that Paul is stating the Day of Christ occurs after the falling away and the revealing of the man of sin then follows. However, there seems to be no grammatical or contextual support for this view that, as I see it.
Anyway, thank you in advance for any input.

Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play our in practice. Good question ; up-voted +1.

Thank you, I originally posted in hermeneutics and did not see much of a similar question there - it was merged here and I have since seen very similar questions answered.

Related:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/74961/47250

I'll use The Legacy Standard Bible (LSB) here as it's favored by John MacArthur and shows that there's variances here with different manuscripts.
2 Thessalonians 2:1-3,

“Now we ask you, brothers, with regard to the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ and our gathering together to Him, that you not be quickly shaken in your mind or be alarmed whether by a spirit or a word or a letter as if from us, to the effect that the day of the Lord has come. Let no one in any way deceive you, for it has not come unless the apostasy comes first, and the man of lawlessness is revealed, the son of destruction,”

John MacArthur said in his sermon on 1 Thessalonians 5:3 (https://www.gty.org/library/sermons-library/52-19/the-day-of-the-lord-part-1):

Now, just a footnote.  It must be distinguished from the day of Christ or the day of the Lord Jesus, or the day of the Lord Jesus Christ, or the day of Jesus Christ.  Those phrases are all used.  The day of Christ is used in Philippians.  The day of the Lord Jesus in 1 and 2 Corinthians.  And the day of the Lord Jesus Christ in 1 Corinthians 1:8.  Now, listen very carefully.  The day of Christ, or the Lord Jesus Christ or the Lord Jesus always has to do with, watch this, believers.  It always has to do with the time of being rewarded by Christ, a time when believers enter in to their redemption and their reward and their eternal glory.  The day of Christ then associates with the Rapture, and the redemption and reward of saints.  The day of the Lord associates with judgment on the ungodly.

Neither 1 or 2 Thessalonians is included in that list. The NASB and LSB use the phrase day of the Lord in those books. In Thessalonians, some manuscripts have the day of the Lord and some have the day of Christ. MacArthur, in his commentaries, uses the day of the Lord, and so it seems that he prefers those manuscripts over the Textus Receptus.
In light of that, there would be nothing to explain away here as it is using "the day of the Lord" and referring to the coming punishment of unbelievers.

Doesn't this overlook Paul's clear and direct connection between Christ's return and our gathering to Him? Paul seems to be addressing a singular event, and one he previously discussed with the Thessalonians. In 1 Thessalonians 4 and 5, the rapture (4:16-17) flows seamlessly into Chapter 5, with no textual or grammatical indication of a separate event. Instead, Paul seems to continue his discussion of the Chapter 4 event and connects this day with the destruction of those in darkness (non-believers). This often feels like doctrine defines the reading rather than reading defining doctrine.

John MacArthur (and I) holds to a pre-tribulation rapture – the rapture immediately precedes the great tribulation. The main reasoning that would be given to have the rapture be a distinct event from the day of the Lord would be that the day of the Lord is a series of judgments on the world. The Church does not need judgment as Christ died for her and is raptured before the tribulation. So, the rapture is connected to the day of the Lord but could be thought of as a separate event as it deals explicitly with the Church and not with the world. The rapture and the day of the Lord are a series of events and are connected to each other, with the rapture kicking off the day of the Lord. They are distinctly connected to each other but could be thought of as different events as the rapture (day of Christ) deals with the Church and the day of the Lord deals with destruction of those in darkness.
Note: this is the first time (that I recall) that I've heard that there's a distinction between day of the Lord and day of Christ, but looking at the passages in non-Textus Receptus translations, I can see how you could get that.
Note: The LSB is a direct update of the NASB 1995 edition

Doesn't this overlook Paul's clear and direct connection between Christ's return and our gathering to Him? Paul seems to be addressing a singular event, and one he previously discussed with the Thessalonians. In 1 Thessalonians 4 and 5, the rapture (4:16-17) flows seamlessly into Chapter 5, with no textual or grammatical indication of a separate event. Instead, Paul seems to continue his discussion of the Chapter 4 event and connects this day with the destruction of those in darkness (non-believers).
This often feels like doctrine defines the reading rather than reading defining doctrine.

@Jacob McDougle This shows how far those of a preconceived doctrine will go to try to support their view. The wording in the KJV leads little doubt that the day of Christ is the same as the ( coming of our Lord Jesus Christ)- see 2nd Th. verses chapter 2 verses 1& 2. In answer to the support you ask for on the timing of Jesus's coming I suggest 2Thch2:8 KJV once again establishes that the brightness of the true coming of Jesus both reveals and destroys the imposter or man of sin ( aka son of perdition) who sits in the temple deceiving many

@RHPclass79 I agree with you. Would you consider contributing your answer to this question ? I think you have the substance for it in your comment.

@Nigel J. I will consider your advice. I thought a comment might not result in a drawn out debate, being comments are sometimes more opinionated. Good to communicate with you.

I'll edit my answer hopefully tomorrow regarding your question @JacobMcDougle. I haven't had the time to do it today.

@JasonJ I’m wondering if you’d be interested in responding to my related post Day of Lord vs Day of Jesus Christ. I believe it challenges the idea of such terms being references to separate events. Thank you for your response.

By a greek new translator of Bible
My friend, I will answer you with a single verse. Because I had the same issue back in the day, and I did a whole paper to prove that "rapture" doesn't exist. I should note that the word "rapture" does not exist in the N.T. There is only the word "ἀρπαγησώμεθα ἐν νεφέλαις", which means "we shall be raptured on clouds". Resurrection of the dead and Transfiguration of the living are one thing, one point in time. So I answer you with this: "Τοῦτο γάρ ἐστιν τὸ θέλημα τοῦ πατρός μου, ἵνα πᾶς ὁ θεωρῶν τὸν υἱὸν καὶ πιστεύων εἰς αὐτὸν ἔχῃ ζωὴν αἰώνιον· καὶ ἀναστήσω αὐτὸν ἐγὼ ἐν τῇ ἐσχάτῃ ἡμέρᾳ." Which means, "For this is the will of my Father, that everyone who sees/observes the Son and believes in him shall have eternal life; and I will raise him up in the last day." There is no rapture!

You claim the rapture doesn’t exist because the term isn’t in Scripture, yet you translate ἀρπαγησώμεθα ἐν νεφέλαις in 1 Thess 4:17 as including the term “rapture" - if accurate, doesn't this contradict your point? Regardless, the absence of a specific word does not equate to the absence of the concept—terms like "omnipresent" or "omniscient" aren’t in Scripture, but I presume you wouldn't argue they are not true reflections of two aspects of God. Ultimately, I'd argue the concept of a rapture, or sudden removal, is found in places like  1 Thess 4:17, Acts 8:39, 2 Cor 12:2-4, and elsewhere.

@JacobMcDougle I apologize for not also writing the "concept" or "implication" of the rapture, concepts which are not found at all in the New Testament. I also apologize for misspelling the word; "ἁρπαγησόμεθα" is the correct word. As for the verses you quoted, they do not answer my response. 1 Thess. 4:15-17 (not just 4:17); Acts 8:39 and 2 Cor. 12:2-4 make no reference to the so-called "secret rapture", or "visible rapture", whatever you want to call it. What do you not understand from the quote I quoted in the reply? The last day is the last day, and not some day before the last day.

First, it doesn't seem as if you've read my initial question/post in the first place (see the start of the second paragraph for my stance on the matter distinguishing separate events or not). Furthermore, the very implication of the Greek term is a sudden seizing or snatching away, and the passages I highlighted do display such an event. Lastly, in 1 Thess 4:15-17, if you want an even clearer image of the event look to the Greek word used for "meet" (ἀπάντησιν). This would also convey the idea of believers meeting Christ to then escort Him to his earthly throne.

@JacobMcDougle You are forcing me to deal with a subject that I have resolved with myself. But let me say a few more things. First, pay attention to 2 Peter 3:7-13. There is no millennial kingdom on earth. The last day is the judgment and destruction of the earth, according to the scriptures, as we read them. To refer to a paragraph in Revelation, a book which is apocalyptic and needs revelation to interpret, is absurd.

@JacobMcDougle All through the Bible, you have the phrases "day of the Lord," "day of judgment," "presence of the Lord," "last day," "presence of God," etc. that says "sudden day of rapture"? Okay, it implies that; then tell me where it implies that?

@JacobMcDougle I am sorry, i forgot that you did the question. My false.

That is precisely what the Greek word implies: a sudden removal or snatching away from somewhere. This is why it is also used in the verses I shared, such as Acts 8:39 (I mistakenly wrote 8:29 earlier; my apologies) and 2 Corinthians 12:2–4. Why would Paul, under the guidance of the Spirit, choose such a specific term if not for a specific implication?
This will be my final response, as back-and-forth comments that introduce related topics—while interesting and worthy of discussion—distract from the main point of the post. Thank you, and God bless.

@JacobMcDougle You suspect that the "rapture" is likely to happen after the fall, or apostasy. So I say to you, there is no rapture before the final judgment, before the 2nd coming of the Lord Jesus Christ. No distinction is made between the last day of "the day of Christ" and "the day of the Lord". It is the same thing. Paul says "we shall be raptured up (suddenly) in a cloud" because, it is understood, not because God's people will suddenly leave the world and the world will remain a few more years, but because there will be a condemnation of sinners, heaven and earth will be destroyed.

@JacobMcDougle parable of the weeds

@JacobMcDougle The believers then had a suspicion, or an expectation of the day of the Lord. Paul interrupted them, telling them that that day would not come unless the lawless one came first. And do not wait for that day and be anxious. Moreover, not everyone who says: "Lord, Lord", will enter the kingdom, but he who does the will of God. The resurrection-transformation-rapture will happen once. Then the door was closed. see. ten virgins. See. example Noah, see. two in the field and one is taken, just like two in the millstone and one is taken.
